# How can I chunk a dataframe so that I could determine which cells in each chunk have the value 1?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not very experienced at this, so I'll try my best to lay out the probelm:
I have a pandas dataframe of 559000 rows x 1 columns and I would like to chunk it in a way that each chunk is 1000 pieces long. Then I would like to iterate over one chunk at a time in order to find the cells that have the value 1. Your help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a chunk reader;

```
reader = pd.read_csv('path_to/your_file', chunksize=1000)
```

Iterate over each chunks in the reader;

```
for chunk in reader:
    # ... your logic ...
```

**Note:** chunks behave like normal data-frames.